# crear distintos dataframe en función de los valores de una columna

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo el siguiente DataFrame:

```
    Comunidad_autonoma  Combustible Unidad
0   Andalucía   Diésel  3065
1   Andalucía   Eléctrico   26
2   Andalucía   Gas licuado (GLP)   10
3   Andalucía   Gas natural (CNG)   4
4   Andalucía   Gasolina    1260
... ... ... ...
95  País Vasco  Gas licuado (GLP)   1
96  País Vasco  Gas natural (CNG)   2
97  País Vasco  Gasolina    334
98  País Vasco  Híbrido 17
99  País Vasco  Híbrido enchufable  10
100 rows × 3 columns
```

Necesito crear distintos Dataframe en función de la comunidad autónoma, debería quedar algo así:
dataframe andalucia

```
Comunidad_autonoma  Combustible Unidad
0   Andalucía   Diésel  3065
1   Andalucía   Eléctrico   26
2   Andalucía   Gas licuado (GLP)   10
3   Andalucía   Gas natural (CNG)   4
4   Andalucía   Gasolina    1260
```

dataframe país vasco

```
Comunidad_autonoma  Combustible Unidad

95  País Vasco  Gas licuado (GLP)   1
96  País Vasco  Gas natural (CNG)   2
97  País Vasco  Gasolina    334
98  País Vasco  Híbrido 17
99  País Vasco  Híbrido enchufable  10
```

y así con las demás comunidades:
he probado con el siguiente código:

```
lista_comunidades=['Navarra','Extremadura','Aragón','Andalucía','Asturias',
                   'Islas Baleares','Islas Canarias','Cantabria','Castilla la Mancha',
                    'Castilla y León','Cataluña','Comunidad Valenciana','Galicia',
                    'Madrid','Murcia','País Vasco','La Rioja']

lista=[]

for comunidad in lista_comunidades:
   
    variable =df2020.loc[df2020.Comunidad_autonoma == comunidad] 
    lista.append(variable)
```

La lista guardaría los distintos dataframe, y así poder luego pintarlos en graficos

Comment: ¿Qué ocurre con el código que has probado? ¿No te funciona? ¿Por qué?

Comment: No me añade nada a la lista, se queda vacia

Comment: ah, creo que te sobra el `.loc` De todas formas es preferible la solución que doy en la respuesta

Comment: Perfecto ahora lo compruebo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `df.groupby()` puede ser de utilidad. Te agrupará el dataframe por la columna que le indiques, generando así varios "sub-dataframes" (o grupos) de modo que en cada uno de ellos el valor sea el mismo para esa columna. En tu caso lo usaríamos para agrupar por la columna `Comunidad_autonoma`.

Lo que te devuelve es un iterable. Si iteras sobre él cada iteración te dará un par: `(clave, grupo)` siendo `clave` el valor repetido en ese grupo (la comunidad autónoma) y `grupo` el sub-dataframe extraído.

Gracias a esto es fácil construir un diccionario (que creo que sería más apropiado que una lista en tu caso) en el que las claves sean las diferentes comunidades y los valores sean los dataframes pandas con los valores de esa comunidad. Así:

```
resultado = {comunidad: grupo 
             for comunidad, grupo in df2020.groupby("Comunidad_autonoma")}
```

Con los datos de ejemplo que has dado en la pregunta, el resultado sería el siguiente diccionario (obtenido con `pprint.pprint(resultado)`):

```
{
'Andalucía':
   Comunidad_autonoma        Combustible  Unidad
0          Andalucía             Diésel  3065.0
1          Andalucía          Eléctrico    26.0
2          Andalucía  Gas licuado (GLP)    10.0
3          Andalucía  Gas natural (CNG)     4.0
4          Andalucía           Gasolina  1260.0,

'País Vasco':
    Comunidad_autonoma         Combustible  Unidad
95         País Vasco   Gas licuado (GLP)     1.0
96         País Vasco   Gas natural (CNG)     2.0
97         País Vasco            Gasolina   334.0
98         País Vasco          Híbrido 17     NaN
99         País Vasco  Híbrido enchufable    10.0
}
```

Naturalmente puedes acceder a los dataframes individuales de una comunidad accediendo a `resultado[comunidad]`

Comment: A funcionado a la perfección! Muchas gracias! Mi respuesta también funciona al final, la celda por lo que sea no funcionaba, pero lo he copiado en otra y si iba.